# What does $2^{\mathbb {R}}$ mean?

Tags: notation

I was looking around on the internet ( as one does) and found the expression $$2^{\mathbb {R}}$$ To me this reads as 2 two the power of the real numbers. But what does that mean? Does it mean the set of all $2^x$ where $x$ is a real number?

Comment: The set of all mappings from $\mathbb R$ to $\{0,1\}$, maybe?

Comment: If $A$ is a set, then $2^A$ usually means the set of all subsets of $A$.  This is the same as Oscar Lanzi's comment, by the way.

Comment: But it can also be $\{2^x | x \in \mathbb{R}\}$, i.e. the set of all numbers of the form $2^x$ for some $x \in \mathbb{R}$, as you noted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It usually denotes the set of all subsets of $\mathbb{R}.$ This is almost certainly the case here, but you've provided no explicit context.